# What will be the state of DNA in actively protein producing cells?

Tags: cells

DNA which is not condensed will not stain much as the Condensed dna. In case of actively protein producing cells, there will be de condensation of dna isn’t it? Then what is mentioned in my book has to be wrong right? Please anyone clarify it or am I wrong?[image]

Comment: I think the book is supposed to say, "when the cells are not *dividing*, DNA is not as condensed...". Your confusion is warranted. During interphase, DNA is being transcribed to direct protein synthesis. Not all of it, but some. Staining is relative; you won't see organized chromosomes but the DNA still stains, just much less than when it's dividing. [This](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/chromosomes-14121320/) might help. Also, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euchromatin). It's unfortunate that the statement seems to exist in multiple editions of that textbook.

Comment: So during interphase( not dividing) because the cell is actively producing protein, dna is not as much condensed as dividing cells.( helpful for transcription) so can I just neglect that sentence as wrong one? Thanks a lot @anongoodnurse

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.